# Is it possible to automate a complex task without using apps or rooting? If not, which is recommended?

Tags: automation, openvpn

So, we are part of a company that provides VPN services to retailers. One of our clients doesn't want to have their employees open up the VPN and login every time they turn the device (an Android tablet) on. This involves opening up OpenVPN, putting in credentials and clicking the Connect button. Is this possible natively, without rooting - opening up an app and putting in credentials automatically - or do I absolutely need an external app? If so, which app is the most recommended in this case?

Comment: The implementation of your VPN app is a bit bizarre. Why does it force its user to login every time? It can save a token for the authenticated user credentials and use that token to auto-login every time the app is opened up. Even opening the app is not necessary. Always-on VPN Android functionality can also be utilized if the user should always be using VPN so long as the device is used by them.

Comment: Hello @Firelord♦, we use OpenVPN, it doesn't force the user to login every time, but the retailer wants it to press the "connect" button automatically. You know what I mean? It has to auto start and auto connect.

Comment: OpenVPN is an open source protocol. There are many free and commercial products for almost every OS which use this protocol. You mean you use OpenVPN Android Client app? You can develop a simple OpenVPN based app of your own which behaves the way you want it. Both OpenVPN and Android's VPNService API are open source.